# Formulario dinámico con Laravel y Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, formularios, laravel-blade

Estoy realizando un formulario en donde la persona debe solicitar distintos materiales, quiero hacer esto en un solo formulario para no hacerlo 1 por 1. Pero llegue a un punto en donde no sé como solucionar el problema.

Tengo lo siguiente:

Blade:

```
<div id="formulario">
    <label for="Material">Material</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <select name="inventario[]['nombre']" class="form-control col-md-6">
            @foreach ($inventario as $inventarios)
            <option value="{{ $inventarios->IdInventario }}">
                {{ $inventarios->Descripcion }}
            </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <input type="number" class="form-control col-md-6 @error('Cantidad') is-invalid @enderror" name="inventario[]['cantidad']" placeholder="Cantidad a solicitar" required> @error('Cantidad')
        <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>

<div id="clon"></div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#clonar").click(function() {
            $("#formulario").clone().appendTo("#clon");
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Controlador:

```
public function save(Request $request){

        SolicitudMaterial::create([
            'NumeroSolicitud' => $request->NumSolicitud,
            'IdInventario' => $request->get('Material'),
            'Cantidad' => $request->Cantidad,
            'IdEstado' => 2,
        ]);
}
```

No he podido conseguir guardar esos items al momento, ya que solo se me guarda 1.

Así es cuando hay uno:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/Ff6UGCc.png]

Lo que quiero conseguir es guardar los que sean:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Leí que el name debe ser un array, pero lo que no logro es hacer una diferencia entre el formulario que ya está y los nuevos que se agregan ni tampoco leerlo en el controlador para poder guardarlo.

Sé que el método en el controlador esta malo y posiblemente haya que utilizar un foreach para recorrer los array, pero eso es lo que no sé como implementarlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que tenés que clonar es el `.input-group`, si clonas el `#formulario` vas a tener el ID repetido, lo cual no es válido.

Por otro lado, si bien los nombres de los campos tienen que ser arrays, si los armás como los tenés, vas a tener un problema. Cada vez que aparece un campo *array* (`inventario[][nombre]`, `inventario[][cantidad]`) se le suma 1 a la clave, con lo cual terminás con un array del estilo:

```
inventario[0][nombre]
inventario[1][cantidad]
inventario[2][nombre]
inventario[3][cantidad]
```

Y no lo que estás esperando:

```
inventario[0][nombre]
inventario[0][cantidad]
inventario[1][nombre]
inventario[1][cantidad]
```

Podrías desde JS asegurarte de agregar el ID correspondiente, pero lo más fácil es simplemente usar nombres distintos: `nombres[]` y `cantidades[]`. De esa forma sabes que el nombre `0` corresponde a la cantidad `0`.

```js
$('.clonar').click(function() {
  // Clona el .input-group
  var $clone = $('#formulario .input-group').last().clone();

  // Borra los valores de los inputs clonados
  $clone.find(':input').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is('select')) {
      this.selectedIndex = 0;
    } else {
      this.value = '';
    }
  });

  // Agrega lo clonado al final del #formulario
  $clone.appendTo('#formulario');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="formulario">
  <label for="Material">Material</label>
  <button type="button" class="clonar btn btn-secondary btn-sm">+</button>
  <div class="input-group">
    <select name="nombres[]" class="form-control col-md-6">
      <option value="1">
        Material 1
      </option>
      <option value="2">
        Material 2
      </option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" class="form-control col-md-6 @error('Cantidad') is-invalid @enderror" name="cantidades[]" placeholder="Cantidad a solicitar" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controlador:**

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
    // Recorre todos los "nombres" enviados, si no hay ninguno se
    //  crea un array vacío para que no devuelva un error el foreach
    foreach ($request->input('nombres', []) as $i => $nombre) {
        SolicitudMaterial::create([
            'NumeroSolicitud' => $request->NumSolicitud,
            'IdInventario'    => $nombre,
            'Cantidad'        => $request->input('cantidades.' . $i),
            'IdEstado'        => 2,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muy completa tu respuesta, me ha servido, muchas gracias.

Comment: Aunque quería saber si me podías ayudar con algo más, ya que a la hora de clonar, el campo de select se resetea y sale en blanco, me gustaría que se viera el nombre y no un espacio en blanco, ya que a nivel de diseño si afecta un poco la experiencia del usuario. https://i.imgur.com/JLRwNJH.png

Comment: @ScriptKash ahí edité el código para que se seleccione la primera opción del select al clonar.